# How to match and partial substitute with sed

Tags: regex, sed

how can i match the substring "2153846-11" (composed sometimes by only numbers, like "2153846", sometimes like "2153846-11" or "2153846_11", sometimes like "2153846-1" always digits and in the first group no less then 5) inside the following:

```
"01/16/2015","2153846-11","2015-01-16 02:50:18.0","lch_demo_hidemi-19459072-2","","01/16/2015"
```

and substitute the matched string with the first group (before dash/underscore) removing the second one.

The final result will be:

```
"01/16/2015","2153846","2015-01-16 02:50:18.0","lch_demo_hidemi-19459072-2","","01/16/2015"
```

The instruction will be written a unique sed line like

```
sed -e 's/...//g' < myfile
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed 's/"\([0-9]*\)[_-][0-9]*"/"\1"/g' file
"01/16/2015","2153846","2015-01-16 02:50:18.0","lch_demo_hidemi-19459072-2","","01/16/2015"
```

Comment: Sed returns "Function ... cannot be parsed" i think the problem is in the backreference, is it possible?

Comment: I'm not able to get version, i know that OS is AIX

Comment: ok try this command on AIX: `sed  's/"\([0-9]*\)[_-][0-9]*"/"\1"/g' file`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below sed command.

```
$ echo '"01/16/2015","2153846-11","2015-01-16 02:50:18.0","lch_demo_hidemi-19459072-2","","01/16/2015"' | sed -r 's/"(2153846)([_-]11)?"/"\1"/g'
"01/16/2015","2153846","2015-01-16 02:50:18.0","lch_demo_hidemi-19459072-2","","01/16/2015"
```